# How do you generate services etc. for a @nrwl/nx angular-cli app?

Tags: angular-cli, nrwl

Normally when using @angular/cli to develop an application, you add a new service in the following manner:

`ng generate service foo`

This would generate "FooService".

My question is, when you have generated a library using @nrwl/nx, how do you add a service to it?

`ng generate lib foo-lib`

What I want to know, is the command to generate service "foo", so that it lives in the foo-lib library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It just works with the angular-cli command, but you have to add the --app flag

```
ng g service foo --app=foo-lib
```

It is also mentioned in the docs of [Nx](https://nrwl.io/nx/guide-nx-workspace) under "Leverage the AngularCLI".

Comment: In recent versions, Nx uses project.json, instead of angular.json for project configs, so there's no ng workspace and the above command won't work. Therefore @Andrew's is the only working answer.

Answer (score 19):

For nx vesion **6.1**, this is the right way:

```
ng g service my-service --project=myNameOrLibName
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm using version `15.7.2` of Nx. I couldn't find anything in the online documentation that discussed how to create an angular service, which I believe is a fault in the Nx docs. Then, I tried the following and was able to create a service.

Here's the command I used:

```
npx nx g @nrwl/angular:service services/my-service --project=my-project
```

Comment: The docs clearly describes it here: https://nx.dev/nx-api/angular#fallback-to : If you try to invoke a generator that is not present in @nx/angular, the request will automatically be forwarded on to @schematics/angular, So, even though there is no @nx/angular:service generator, the following command will successfully create a service: nx g @nx/angular:service my-service

Comment: @KavehG On Feb 28th, I let the Nx people know about the lack of documentation by filing a [bug](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/15341). On Mar 3rd, they updated the documentation to make explicit this fallback behavior. So, of course it **"clearly describes"** the behavior thanks to me. Here is the [edit to the docs](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/commit/6dee75f08cda6b534d475cfb10cd6fa01c0f67d6) including date of change.

Comment: In version 16.10.0 I ran it like this:  `npx nx g @nx/angular:service ./services/my-service`

Answer (score 1):

Nx is a wrapper around angular cli. Everything you do using Angular-cli, you pretty much do in nx workspaces. Only difference being the custom schematic that nx provides that helps you achieve mono-repo and re-use code across multiple apps within your company. When in doubt, just run any commands with --dry-run and see if things being generated are the things you want and you should be good.